# Not able to make postgres database call on heroku using Play Framework Application

Tags: postgresql, heroku, playframework, heroku-postgres, playframework-2.5

I am build REST api using play framework 2.8 , I am able to start the application and call some service. Facing issue when trying to connecting with postgres database. Logs are below -

```
Error opening connection for database: {}org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "3.87.112.32", user "abc", database "xyz", SSL off
```

Tried looking solution for this and foudn have to add `sslmode=require` in query param while connection to database.

When log the url sslmode is already mentioned.

```
jdbc:postgresql://abc.amazonaws.com:5432/xyz?password=1234&sslmode=require&user=xyz
```

I am reading this property from heroku env variable `JDBC_DATABASE_URL`  for obtaining database connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue can be fixed by adding addition query parameters apart from `sslmode=require` which are `ssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory` after adding this the new URL become `jdbc:postgresql://abc.amazonaws.com:5432/xyz?password=1234&sslmode=require&user=xyzssl=true&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory`